# How do I design a swipe/slide function in Qt to select a widget?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, widget

I would like to create a GUI interface as per the attached pic
[[image: GUI Menu example [1]]

My main issue is the central slider widget..as you can see I would like to create a function choosing widget that the user can slide left and right then click on the desired cook function..

Unfortunately it has to be done with Qt C++ widget not QML.

Comment: have you tried [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) class?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish that.

One would be arranging the small widgets next to each other manually, using `setGeometry()`. Overlay the complete visible area of the parent with a transparent widget. Reimplement the `mouseEvents` in that overlay and use the move, press click events to decide how to move the small widgets (by repeatedly calling setGeometry on them with other coordinates) or whether one has been clicked.

Should be very lightweighted and straight forward to implement and allows complete control. Would be also easy to change the sizes by calling setGeometry) with a different size to model a fluid zoom effect. E.g. to have the center widget bigger than the peripheral.

You may also have a look at `QScroller` which should help you with the scrolling control.

Comment: Thanks Aaron
I used ListView in QML to accomplish a similar feel but it seems different in c++ GUI implementation.
Is there no direct way of doing it? something similar to ListView?

Comment: As far as I know, scrolling by dragging on the items is not supported, yet. You can also combine the mentioned transparent overlay with a `QScrollArea` to control it's scroll position. You may find this an easier approach.

Answer (score 2):

How about Qt gestures ? Haven't used it but looks like your use-case.

reference:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/gestures-overview.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qswipegesture.html

You could capture the gesture on your widget and do actions like:

```
bool ImageWidget::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
{
   if (QGesture *swipe = event->gesture(Qt::SwipeGesture))
        swipeTriggered(static_cast<QSwipeGesture *>(swipe));
    return true;
}

void ImageWidget::swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture *gesture)
{
    if (gesture->state() == Qt::GestureFinished) {
        if (gesture->horizontalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Left) {
            // highlight the right widget , you could even bring it to center
        } else if (gesture->horizontalDirection() == QSwipeGesture::Right) {
            // highlight the left widget , you could even bring it to center
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am thinking of using the abstract wheel widget class as a basis and go from there...It is used in the QScroller example...I will update you guys on my progress